# How can I compare two XML files and return only modified elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to compare two **XML** files and return the associated sub element that was modified. If in the below **XML** files the Action Parameters are modified. I would like the script to return the `USER_GID` of the modified `ACTION_PARAMETERS`. Please suggest a **XML** diff utility or a custom script to accomplish the same.

File 1:

```
<ROW num="1">
      <USER_GID>-WORK CREATED</USER_GID>
      <ACTION_FLOW>Test</ACTION_FLOW>
      <ACTION_SEQUENCE>1</ACTION_SEQUENCE>
      <USER_ACTION_GID>IFCASE</USER_ACTION_GID>
      <ACTION_PARAMETERS>-forceTrue false -savedCondition {ABC.Check For Details} -role ADMIN -user 58250</ACTION_PARAMETERS>
      <CREATE_NEW_PROCESS>N</CREATE_NEW_PROCESS>
      <DOMAIN_NAME>ABC</DOMAIN_NAME>
      <INSERT_USER>58250</INSERT_USER>
      <INSERT_DATE>7/13/2016 14:23:37</INSERT_DATE>
      <UPDATE_USER>TESTUSER</UPDATE_USER>
      <UPDATE_DATE>6/16/2017 14:3:25</UPDATE_DATE>
</ROW>
```

File 2:

```
<ROW num="1">
      <USER_GID>-WORK CREATED</USER_GID>
      <ACTION_FLOW>Test</ACTION_FLOW>
      <ACTION_SEQUENCE>1</ACTION_SEQUENCE>
      <USER_ACTION_GID>IFCASE</USER_ACTION_GID>
      <ACTION_PARAMETERS>-savedCondition {ABC.Check For Details} -role ADMIN -user 58250</ACTION_PARAMETERS>
      <CREATE_NEW_PROCESS>N</CREATE_NEW_PROCESS>
      <DOMAIN_NAME>ABC</DOMAIN_NAME>
      <INSERT_USER>58250</INSERT_USER>
      <INSERT_DATE>7/13/2016 14:23:37</INSERT_DATE>
      <UPDATE_USER>TESTUSER</UPDATE_USER>
      <UPDATE_DATE>6/16/2017 14:3:25</UPDATE_DATE>
</ROW>
```

On running the Diff in the above scenario I expect the output to be "WORK CREATED"

Comment: Your `File 2` has `<AGENT_ACTION_GID>...</USER_ACTION_GID>`. That cannot work.

Comment: In XSLT 2.0 there is a `deep-equal()` function.

Comment: Hi Michael, It is a typo and should be USER_ACTION_GID I have corrected it

Answer (score 0):

Could it be as simple as:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:param name="path-to-file2" select="'file2.xml'"/>

<xsl:template match="/ROW">
    <xsl:if test="ACTION_PARAMETERS != document($path-to-file2)/ROW/ACTION_PARAMETERS">
        <xsl:value-of select="USER_GID"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

?